# How to run C# NUnit automation tests from bibucket.org repository using jenkins localhost instance?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automation, nunit

I am trying to run the C# automation tests which are present in a repository which is located at the bitbucket.org (It is a remote repository). The project uses C# and NUnit framework. I totally got stuck and not getting what exact steps to follow to run the tests from the remote repository.
Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this? Thanks.

I tried installing a jenkins instance locally and tried running the tests. But I am not able to run tests.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Install necessary Jenkins plugins: NUnit Plugin and .NET Core Plugin.

Configure your project on Jenkins. You need to define a build job for your project.

Source Code Management: Choose Git and provide the URL of your bibucket.org repository.

Build Triggers: You can set this to Poll SCM to check for changes every few minutes or trigger builds remotely.

Build: In the Build section, you can choose between MSBuild and .NET Core (dotnet) commands. For C# NUnit tests, you should have a target in your project file (usually .csproj) that restores, builds, and runs tests.
for example:

```
<Target Name="Test">
<Exec Command="dotnet test" />
```

Post-build Actions: You can configure Jenkins to publish NUnit test results by providing the path to your test result XML file(s). The file path should be relative to your workspace.

Save the build job configuration.

Start the build job to run the tests. Jenkins will check out the source code from your bibucket.org repository, build the project, and run the tests. If everything is configured correctly, you should see the test results in the build job.

You can follow this link to understand how to set up Jenkins: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/